# Togaf tool modeling

Tags: togaf

I am a newbie in Togaf and I need to start a first trial.
I am trying to model my architecture.
Which tool do you advise me to use in order to model my architecture using TOGAF?

Answer (score 9):

You may start using the [ArchiMate](http://www.opengroup.org/subjectareas/enterprise/archimate) modelling language, and as a tool you can try [Archi](http://www.archimatetool.com/), I recommend to start with this one because it's free and you can do a lot with it. You will also find a lot of tutorials and other material to help you to get started.

I'm in the same situation as you and I'm starting this way.

Answer (score 1):

Following the book "Modeling Enterprise Architecture with TOGAF", I have used  [Modelio](https://www.modelio.org/)  with the [Togaf Module](http://www.togaf-modeling.org/)

Answer (score 1):

While I can't speak to how well it does (or does not) work with TOGAF you might want to check out [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html) by Sparx Systems. I've used Enterprise Architect for various architecture models over the years and it is very good in this respect. The ability to reuse "artifacts" within the tool was great as well as the built-in reporting capabilities. There were also tons of features that I never took advantage of. A very capable tool but has a corresponding cost to go along with that :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in embedded step-by-step guide-through instructions, samples and requirement tools for developing deliverables, [Visual Paradigm's Enterprise Edition](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/togaf-adm-tool-for-enterprise-architecture.jsp) may be your choice.

They offer two different mode:

1. Guide-through process which provides you TOGAF ADM process navigator to traverse through each of the development phases from Preliminary, and A to H phase.
2. Furthermore, if you need to customize the project they also office a process composer called Just-in-Time TOGAF project which allows you to add, remove and customer the steps and activities to fit your specific needs

Take a look of the demo here for ([Guide-through](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=24&v=gEbCFfgxc0s))

Answer (score 1):

Our Architecture group went through a TOGAF training class, and the recommended tool which we were told about is [Archi](https://www.archimatetool.com/).  I've starting using it as I'm starting on a couple of new projects, and the response I've gotten from my business partners (who are a fairly important stakeholder) has been positive.

I'll be honest, you can do most of the same kind of thing in Visio (where we used to do it) or in any other tool.  The important thing is to get everybody on the SAME tool, and figure out how to use it and come up with standards that your organization will adhere to.

One other benefit of Archi is it's free.  As a result, I've been getting our Tech Leads and our Data Architects to download it in order to review the models I'm coming up with, and hopefully add to it and possibly do some of their design work in it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Considering an Enterprise Architecture environment as target, it's better to opt for a centralized knowledge management system, where all kind of documentation and architecture deliverable will be stored, maintained and made available to all users.

In my company we use Atlassian Confluence  with giffy plugin, there are for sure other alternatives but it  works quite well.

I don't like Archimate because I found it rough not user friendly and unintuitive.

For a single installation Microsoft Visio can create very high quality professional Architecture deliverables